# Query on java I/O BufferedOutputStream write() method

Tags: java, io, buffers

Below is the code that is written using byte stream non-buffer class `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` with the usage of explicit user buffers.

```
public class FileCopyUserBuffer{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String inFileStr = "C:\\practice_in.jpg";
        String outFileStr = "C:\\practice_out.jpg";

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try{
            in = new FileInputStream(inFileStr);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFileStr);

            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            byte[] byteBuf = new byte[4096];
            int numBytesRead;

            while((numBytesRead = in.read(byteBuf)) != -1){
                out.write(byteBuf, 0, numBytesRead);
            }

        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the program written using byte based buffer I/O stream class `BufferedOutputStream` & `BufferedInputStream`.

```
public class FileCopyBufferedStream{
    public void main(String[] args){

        String inFileStr = "C:\\practice_in.jpg";
        String outFileStr = "C:\\practice_out.jpg";

        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;


        File fileIn = new File(inFileStr);
        System.out.println("File size is: " + fileIn.length() + " bytes");

        try{
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFileStr));
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileStr));

            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            int byteRead;
            while((byteRead = in.read()) != -1){
                out.write(byteRead);
            }

        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above two programs perform the same functionality but am not clear about the functionality of `write(#bytes)` method of `class BufferedOutputStream`.

Based on the observation, below two classes have their own buffers.

```
public class BufferedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    .........
    protected volatile byte buf[];
    ..........
}

public  class BufferedOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
    ........
    protected byte buf[];
    .......
}
```

In second program, How does `out` object of `class BufferedOutputStream` is able to write the buffer that is part of `class BufferedInputStream`? Because we are not passing buffer as argument of `out.write(#bytes)` method[which looks non-intuitive] unlike the first program which passes user  buffer `out.write(byteBuf,,)`? In second program, `out` object should at-least have access to object reference `in` to access the buffer populated using `in.read()`.

Comment: The `InputStream.read(...)` method is overloaded. Calling `read()` without any arguments returns ***"the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached."***. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because we are not passing buffer as argument of out.write(#bytes) method[which looks non-intuitive] unlike the first program which passes user buffer out.write(byteBuf,,)?

No, you are not passing buffer as argument,
you are passing the single byte that you have read.
You have that single byte in the `byteRead` variable,
returned by `BufferedInputStream`,
and you are passing that single byte into `BufferedOutputStream`.

> In second program, out object should at-least have access to object reference in to access the buffer populated using in.read().

No, `BufferedOutputStream` doesn't have access to `BufferedInputStream`'s buffer.

It seems you simply misunderstood what `.read()` without arguments really does.
There's nothing magical going on here.

Comment: ya, you are right. Instead of reading byte-by-byte, how do i read  blocks of data in second program?

Comment: ya, this is the question, if i pass `byte[]` user buffer in `write()` method, what is the advantage of using `class BufferedInputStream` & `class BufferedOutputStream`. It would be same as my first program right? i mean,  Does the number of I/O's to disk will decrease if i use `BufferedInputSream`'s `read(buf[])` instead of `FileInputStream`'s `read(buf[])` method?

Comment: Oh ok, In second program, `read()` or `read(buf[])` get the data from buffer that is already read? If yes, when was the data read and available in stream? Because we did not explicitly read and make available in buffer except reading a single byte `read()`?